# Azure File Share: Cannot map network drive

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-files

So I have a storage account and a file share.
But I'm having problems when I try to map the network drive using the code provided by Azure in a powershell script.
I have nothing else in the script. Just copied and pasted the code.
The Test-NetConnection part works fine.
And it seems like everything works fine actually.I get this after running the script:
[image]

But as you can see in the picture - when I run "net use" I don't see any network drives.
Nothing is shown in the Explorer windows either.

If I paste all code direct into the powershell window everything works fine and I get my drive.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

EDIT:
Additional information - I found out that the drive actually is mapped, but as soon as the script is done and not running anymore, it's removed.
If I add "pause" at the end of the script the mapped drive is available until I hit enter in the powershell window to exit the script...
Maybe that's helpful information for anyone to be able to help out here?

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 10 [Version 10.0.19043.1165]. I also have a problem using the command **net use x: /delete**. The share deletes and then reappears a few minutes later. The key issue for this question is: create a PowerShell script with the code does not work and no error is reported. The code must be directly pasted into a PowerShell window prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this...

By adding -Scope "Global" to the New-PSDrive command the mapped drive stays after the script hos stopped running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-PSDrive?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).